# Typo3 v11 Install - Timeout when trying to access frontend or backend

Tags: installation, timeout, typo3, typo3-11.x

I try to start a new Typo3 project with v11 on my local system (Windows 10, XAMPP for Windows 7.4.13, PHP 7.4.13).

The project was created with composer as suggested, using 'composer create-project typo3/cms-base-distribution'.

During the typo3 install process I got no php configuration errors.
In the php.ini I have set max_execution_time to 240, max_input_vars to 1500 and memory_limit to 512M.

After installation however I neither can access frontend nor backend.
I just receive a timeout message in firefox.
Admin Tool is working, though. I get no errors analyzing the database structure.

Has anyone an idea what I am missing?

Comment: how did you install? with composer or how else?

Comment: Do you have a native webserver and database on your system or do you user Docker, DDEV, XAMPP or anything else? Which Webserver, PHP- and Database Server versions do you use? Are there any reports in the webserver error log or the php error log?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not directly related to coding and can't be solved here.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the installation with composer in Windows has still problems.
In my case the database-table be_sessions wasn't created and the installtool wasn't working.
I also used xampp, but an older version than you did use.
I never had any indication that the problems are related to composer so I think that they are still related to TYPO3 itself. The current version 11.0.0 is not considered as stable yet, so usage is experimental or for further development but not advised for production.

Before I installed with ddev and I never remarked any fundamental problems.
I could open frontend, backend and created a content-element without any problems.
Even I use ddev in Windows the operating system is linux, so probably your problems are related to some Windows related issues.

The installation-guide for TYPO3 can be found [here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/).

There never keeps more to say than using either the currently stable version 10 or another operating system.